# in listView renderRow is not calling after setting state

Tags: listview, react-native, react-native-listview

In list view when click on listview data in renderRow showing a tick mark, i wrote like this

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    this.state={
     dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(['row 1', 'row 2'])
    }
  }
 componentDidMount(){
   //After getting data from service i am setting data to the dataSource
 this.setState({ dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(responseData.data.listTeamBySportId) })
 }

    onTeam(rowData,rowID){
        if(this.state.opacity == rowID){
          this.setState({opacity:null})
        }else{
          this.setState({opacity:rowID})
        }
      }
    render(){
     <ListView
                       style={{flex:1}}
                      dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                      renderRow={this.renderData.bind(this)}  
                      renderSeparator={(sectionID, rowID) => <View key=       {`${sectionID}-${rowID}`} style={styles.separator} />}
                      automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}/>
    }
    renderData(rowData,sectionID:number,rowID:number){
            return (
              <View style={styles.subBody}>
                <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.onTeam.bind(this,rowData,rowID)}>
                  <View  style={{backgroundColor:rowData.colorCode,height:44,flexDirection:'row'}}>
                     <View style={styles.centersubBody}>
                        <Text style={{color:'white',fontWeight:'bold',fontSize:17,fontFamily:'Roboto-Medium',marginLeft:10}}>{rowData.location}</Text> 
                     </View>
                    <View style={styles.rightsubBody}>
                        {this.state.opacity == parseInt(rowID) ? (
                        <Image style={{marginRight:5,marginTop:5, width:25, height:25, marginBottom:10}} source={require('image!selected')}/>
                        ):<View></View>}
                   </View>
                  </View>
                </TouchableHighlight>
              </View>
        );
       }
```

**My react-native version is:0.51.0**
Here the problem is when data is upto 10 records my code working after setState in OnTeam function it again render to the renderRow() and show the tick mark, But the problem is when the data is more than 10 records it is not going to the renderRow data, Please give me suggestions that how to solve it any help much appreciated

Comment: I'm facing the same problem and my code is the same as yours. Have you got any solutions? then please share with me. Thanks

Comment: Hello, Have you got the solution?

Answer (score 1):

If u want the list to be re rendered you have to change the data spirce in the state
On the component constructor define this.ds variable which holds the datasource object, and place in the state a variable you will use for the data of the list. 
For example the inital is

```
this.state ={
myDs: this.ds.cloneWithRows([])
}
```

And wheb you want the rerender with new data write

```
this.setState({myDs: this.ds.clone...(arrNewData)};
```

Uope you understood the idea

Comment: already i done like this please see the above code which i updated

Answer (score 0):

as my know, the `listView` component is special. there is a api for listView.dataSource.

```
var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
this.state = {
  dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(['row 1', 'row 2']),
};
```

in my opinions, if you do not use `ds.cloneWithRows`, the data is not change

Comment: this.setState({
          dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(responseData.data.listTeamBySportId)
        });
when i wrote like this after fetching data the data is not  showing in listView, may i know the reason

Comment: can you please respond

Comment: please respond for it

Comment: can you show me your code? `this.setState({ dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(responseData.data.listTeamBySportId) });`, I can not see  any problem.

Comment: Hi i changed my code above please review it and let me know is there any problem with mycode

Comment: do you a chance to check my code which i updated above?

Comment: sorry, Last week, I had no time. now I check in. and I think the problem in function onTeam. you call the function onTeam to change the ListView  but the ListView will change because the datasource changed. ListView‘s data only use ds.cloneWithRows(['row 1', 'row 2']) to set in. in you function onTeam, you used ` this.setState({opacity:null}) ` that I think it is wrong.

Comment: I'm getting the same problem have you get the solution?

Comment: @KAUSHALJ.SATHWARA What problem? Can you try my solution?